# org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ConversionException : Could not be converted to [class java.util.Date]

Tags: java, oracle, date, jpa, eclipselink

My project is using eclipselink as a JPA provider and after deployment I am facing following exception

> Exception Description: The object [oracle.sql.TIMESTAMPLTZ@2df3825d],
>   of class [class oracle.sql.TIMESTAMPLTZ], from mapping
>   [org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.DirectToFieldMapping[rqstCreateDtTm-->TH01.TY_RQST.RQST_CREATE_DT_TM]]
>   with descriptor
>   [RelationalDescriptor(org.temp.request.model.dataobject.Rqst -->
>   [DatabaseTable(TH01.TY_RQST)])], could not be converted to [class
>   java.util.Date].

java.util.Date field in my entity is as follows

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "RQST_DT_TM")
    private Date rqstDtTm;
```

I have already added following lines in persistence.xml as follows

```
<property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.OraclePlatform" />
```

Note :  I am using Oracle 12 c database and eclipselink:2.5.2

Comment: Why are you specifying the generic OraclePlatform class instead of a more specific Oracle12Platform?  OraclePlatform doesn't include oracle.sql.TIMESTAMPLTZ support.

Comment: I am getting classnot found exception . In which Jar Oracle12Platform class exists?

Comment: I would assume it is in the full (non-osgi) jar, or in the oracle specific OSGI jar: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.persistence/org.eclipse.persistence.oracle

Comment: What would happen if I use Oracle11Platform class for Oracle 12 c database?

Comment: I believe the classes are identical. The Oracle12Platform class is only there to allow for DB metadata major version field lookups.